# Can't seem to figure out why this won't work. python beginner

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to  iterate through a list and every time an item is found in the list it should increment found by 1. For example: count([1,2,1,1], 1) should return 3 (because 1 appears 3 times in the list).

```
def count(sequence, item):
    sequence = []
    found = 0
    for i in sequence:
        if i in item:
            found+=1

    return found
```

Comment: Do try to come up with an actual question title, as it stands now it tells us nothing about what you are asking. You forgot to tell us *what happens instead* (e.g. you get a `TypeError` exception, with the full traceback), or *it always returns 0, whatever I pass in*.

Comment: Why are you setting sequence to be empty?

Answer (score 3):

You want to test for *equality*:

```
if i == item:
    found += 1
```

You are instead testing *containment* with the `in` operator, but using `in` on integers raises an exception instead:

```
>>> item = 1
>>> 1 in item
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

However, you first rebound `sequence` to an empty list:

```
sequence = []
```

so your `for` loop *doesn't even run* as there is nothing to loop over anymore. Working code would instead be:

```
def count(sequence, item):
    found = 0
    for i in sequence:
        if i == item:
            found += 1
    return found
```

Note that list objects have a dedicated method to count matching elements, `list.count()`:

```
>>> sequence = [1, 2, 1, 1]
>>> sequence.count(1)
3
```

Comment: Suprisingly enough, I actually tried that already.here it is. count(sequence, item):
    sequence = []
    found = 0
    for i in sequence:
        if i == item:
            found+=1
    return found

Comment: @user2626734: Yes, and had you actually included a description of what actually happens, I'd have seen the `sequence = []` earlier.

Comment: my bad. I am a noob to this site as well. Here is the error I get. I am doing this on codeacademy. Oops, try again. Your function fails on count([4, 'foo', 5, 'foo'],5). It returns 0 when it should return 1.

Comment: @user2626734: you'd edit your question to add that info.

Answer (score 1):

Martijn Pieters' answer plus remove the line `sequence=[]`. You are overwriting your parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. How long do you think I will have to do python before I stop making these mistakes because they are really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

list objects already have a count method that does exactly what you want :

```
a = [1,1,2,3,4,1,4]
a.count(1) #3
a.count(4) #2
```

If you have a collection of your own custom objects make sure you implement the `__eq__` method on the class definition